# How do I install xvfb and phantomjs on openshift (I'm getting permission denied error)

Tags: linux, openshift, redhat, rhel, xvfb

I'm logged in via SSH through my local ubuntu to this openshift machine.

I've cloned the repo in my local system, added a script, pushed the code and I can see in my openshift account.

However I want to install few dependencies which are not available by default on openshift. e.g. Xvfb and phantomJS.

I tried to install it via yum and npm but getting permission denied error. How could I install these packages or in general if want to install any thing in future how could I.

`yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb` or even `yum install xvfb`

`npm -g install phantomjs`

PS: I'm in `/var/lib/openshift/<some_alphanum_string>`  directory and trying to install here. is this ok?

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is not related to programming. Thus it is off-topic. You can re-ask your question at ServerFault or StackOverflow.

Comment: For phantomjs I just copied/uploaded it to the data to the data directory manually.  From there I was able to access it via the openshift data directory env variable.

Comment: @fatfantasma: Hi, can you please tell me exact steps you followed?

Comment: I downloaded phantomjs to my PC.  I then used Winscp to copy phantomjs to the data directory in my openshift app (python 3.3).   From there you should be able to access it using the openshift environment variable.  Can't remember right now but I think it's something like "OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR".   If you need more info I can give it you tomorrow.  I'm at the beach now. :)